# Identify ethernet adapter

Tags: ethernet, expansion-cards

Please help me identify the maker and model of this 10/100 PCI ethernet adapter. It is entirely unclear to me which information on the PCB might indicate the information I am looking for.

[image: PCB topside]

[image: PCB bottomside]

Searching for various component numbers has not been much help - the best result so far was a sort-of-but-not-quite visual match of components and layout: https://www.pichau.com.br/placa-de-rede-pci-tp-link-10-100mbps-tf-3239dl

I will accept an answer that provides the maker/model or suggestions/process for how to successfully find the information on my own.

Comment: The manufacturer could be anyone.

Comment: FE-1439E is the product name/code. You can find plenty of information using it...?

Comment: The context of my question is that I am often handling old hardware and most of the time it is trivial to tell what manufacturer and model a part is from its markings. I am looking to learn how to better identify parts such as this where there are few to no clear indications.

Comment: @DanielB: Please do write up an answer with what you have found and your process so I can choose your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

That's a Realtek RTL8139C (as written on the big chip).

Drivers are available from the Realtek website (google is your friend, or there is a link [here](https://realtek-download.com/realtek-rtl8139-810x-drivers/))

---

EDIT: Just to add from the comment from Moab, the manufacturer of the PCB could be anyone. Your question was a little open ended and I assumed (rightly or wrongly) that you were after some more information so you could install the card somewhere. Realtek make the chip and generally provide the drivers as well.